# Unexpected Alias behaviour

Tags: alias

Could someone explain to me why the following code outputs what i does?

```
firstlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]
alias = firstlist
firstlist = firstlist*2
print(firstlist)
print(alias)
```

output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]

How come when firstlist is multiplied by two and updated the changes are not reflected in 'alias'. I was under the impression that because 'alias' and 'firstlist' are pointing to the same values, any change made to 'firstlist' should be reflected by 'alias' as well.

Comment: What programming language is this supposed to be?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Assumed Python 3, but maybe others. Expected a more classified question.

Comment: This may be a question talking about _passing by values_ vs _passing by reference_.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on in this line:

```
firstlist = firstlist*2
```

You multiply `firstlist` by two, and then, assign it to a variable, that just happens to `firstlist` - this is not an in place modification. Therefore, `firstlist` and `alias` point to different objects.

On the contrary, if you would modify `firstlist` in place, e.g., by appending to it, you'd see both variables still point to the same object, and have the same value:

```
>>> firstlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]
>>> alias = firstlist
>>> firstlist.extend(firstlist)
>>> print(firstlist)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
>>> print(alias)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
```